# Hide tasks for some (subscribed) calendars in Thunderbird/Lightning

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, lightning

At work I subscribed all my colleagues' calendars to be able to see their appointments and free times for scheduling purposes. But every time I show one of these calendars, Lightning will also show all of that person's tasks in my task list. In some cases, that can be hundreds of entries. For example, if the user has a scheduled task which is repeated every day.

How can I get Lightning to show only events, and not tasks, for specific calendars, without hiding my own tasks?

Answer (score 1):

As of <s>2020</s> 2024 this does not appear to be possible. There are several feature requests in Bugzilla concerning this topic:

- [#1104677: Selecting / Deselecting calendars also selects/deselects tasks (Lightning Add-On)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1104677)
- [#1598592: tasks and calendar view should have different calendar listings and selected calendar](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1598592) (probably a duplicate of 1104677)
- [#1676118: Allow disabling Tasks for individual calendars](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1676118) (which I created)

I also did not find any addons which allow the desired behavior.